# Delete the same row in different gridviews

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

If I have two GridViews that are mirror, that is, they are identical, how can I delete the same row in both GridViews?, that is, if you delete the row 7 in `Gridview1`, row 7 is deleted in `GridView2` too.

I made this code.

```
        Dim UnitIndex As Integer()

        Dim selectedRows() As Integer = GridView1.GetSelectedRows()

        For Each rowHandle As Integer In selectedRows
            If rowHandle >= 0 Then
                UnitIndex = GridView1.GetSelectedRows
            End If
        Next rowHandle

        Dim p As Integer = UnitIndex
        GridView2.DeleteRow(p)
```

Please, could you guide me to do this?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the same source and If a row is deleted the other will delete also.

Or you can handle the [ListChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.listchanged?view=netcore-3.1).when the item is deleted,remove another.

Your code is like this.

```
 Class SurroundingClass
    Private _source1 As BindingList(Of T)

    Public Property Source1 As BindingList(Of T)
        Get
            Return _source1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BindingList(Of T))

            If _source1 <> value Then
                _source1.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
                _source1.ListChanged -= AddressOf Source1_ListChanged
                _source1.ListChanged += AddressOf Source1_ListChanged
                _source1 = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _source2 As BindingList(Of T)

    Public Property Source2 As BindingList(Of T)
        Get
            Return _source2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BindingList(Of T))

            If _source2 <> value Then
                _source2.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
                _source2.ListChanged -= AddressOf Source2_ListChanged
                _source2.ListChanged += AddressOf Source2_ListChanged
                _source2 = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub Source1_ListChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListChangedEventArgs)
        If e.ListChangedType = ListChangedType.ItemDeleted Then
            Source2.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
            Source2.RemoveAt(e.OldIndex)
            Source2.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Source2_ListChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListChangedEventArgs)
        If e.ListChangedType = ListChangedType.ItemDeleted Then
            Source1.RaiseListChangedEvents = False
            Source1.RemoveAt(e.OldIndex)
            Source1.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```